# Leaflet - Mouseover, Click and unclick

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mouseover, highlight

Here is my working example http://members.upcpoczta.pl/w.racek/mapa.html

I would like to achieve is:

1. Keep highlight on mouseover like it is now,
2. When I click on highlighted bicycle route I would like to keep zoom to feature function but when it zooms in to a route I would like to keep highlighting until I click outside selected route or move a map.

Right now it zooms in nicely but when you move mouse highlighting disappears and you don't really know which route you clicked.

Comment: you need to show what you tried to do, read more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To keep the highlighting, I think you can use classes toggling (`toggleClass` on hover and `addClass` on click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, kind of hacky but see it as just a demonstration of how to accomplish something like that. Create a variable `selected`, and store the highlighted feature in there when the `click` handler gets fired. Now in your `mouseout` handler you need to check if a selection is made, see if it corresponds with the layer which fired the `mouseout`, if so, don't remove the highlighted style. Also you would need to write some logic in the `click` handler that if a selection is already made, it removes the highlight from it.

Code example:

```
    function highlight (layer) {
        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            dashArray: ''
        });
        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }
    }

    function dehighlight (layer) {
        if (selected === null || selected._leaflet_id !== layer._leaflet_id) {
            geojson.resetStyle(layer);
        }
    }

    // Variable to store selection
    var selected = null;

    function select (layer) {
        // See if there is already a selection
        if (selected !== null) {
            // Store for now
            var previous = selected;
        }
        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
        // Set new selection
        selected = layer;
        // If there was a previous selection
        if (previous) {
            // Dehighlight previous
            dehighlight(previous);
        }
    }

    var geojson = L.geoJson(rower, {
        style: function (feature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: feature.properties.colour,
                dashArray: 3,
            };
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            'mouseover': function (e) {
                highlight(e.target);
            },
            'mouseout': function (e) {
                dehighlight(e.target);
            },
            'click': function (e) {
              select(e.target);
            }
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fdTnA9CyJdJejiPq2q8M?p=preview

You would also need to write handler for map `click` or `moveend` or whatever ux you're trying to accomplish and in there check if there's a selection, then remove the highlight of it, but that's rather simple once you grasp the concept.

Comment: This works nearly exactly how I wanted. The only small "bug" I see is when you mouse over these 2 blue lines from your example they stay highlighted (both) unless you click one. When you click 1 of them one highligh gets reset and then the function works like it should. Have a look at my page  http://members.upcpoczta.pl/w.racek/mapa.html I have refreshed it with your code. As you can see when the map loads, and you mouseover routes they keep getting highlighted. Only one route at a time should be highlighted. I hope you get me :) To be honest, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I see :D Missed that, must have overlooked something. I'll take a peek when i've got some time and update my answer and Plunker.

Comment: Great! Take your time. :D By the time, I'm studying your code and trying to understand it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Indeed a dumb mistake by me, corrected now, should work as expected

Comment: Hi. That's just dope work. Working great. Thanks a lot!